# Why I don't get the String from the other Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment

hi i want to built a android app that send a text to a other activity but I don't see the input text on the second activity :( I try this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

I make the same how in in this tutorial:

If I click on send I use the Intent class and out this my string ...

here is my code of DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
                if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
                }

                // Get the message from the intent
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

                // Create the text view
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setTextSize(40);
                textView.setText(message);

                // Set the text view as the activity layout
                setContentView(textView);


    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

My First Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    // Button Events

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see 2 activities in your code.

Comment: this is the second ....i post the first too ...moment

Comment: Post your code of MainActivity.Because when you correctly passed in MainActivity & start the current activity (DisplayMessageActivity)  then it comes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get your Bundle in     DisplayMessageActivity

```
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(bundle != null)
            {
                String message = bundle.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            }
```

In sender act. :

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Your title");

                    Activity_A.this.startActivity(intent);
```

MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE is your key pass

Comment: Why not? Can you get your Bundle in DisplayMessageActivity?

Answer (score 2):

use keys to pass message from first activity and get those values in second activity like this

```
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
       value1 = bundle.getString("key1");
        value2 = bundle.getString("key2");
    }
```

In First Activity pass message like this

```
 intent.putExtra("key1", "message1");
 intent.putExtra("key2", "message2");
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

and in the first activity

```
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", "Your title");
```